# RefMut lifetime error when returning from closure

Tags: rust, lifetime, refcell

I have a `RefCell` in my structure which I want to access and modify. However, the only way I can access this `RefCell` is using a closure. Hence, I'd like to return a [mutable reference](https://docs.rs/cell/0.1.5/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) (`RefMut`) from the closure which I can use and modify from the enclosing scope.

```rust
{
    let mut state_ref: RefMut<_> = self.dialog.call_on_name("dirview", |view: &mut Canvas<RefCell<FileDialogState>>| {
        let state: &RefCell<FileDialogState> = view.state_mut();
        state.borrow_mut()
    }).unwrap();

    state_ref.foo = bar;

    // Mutable reference to RefCell should cease to exist here
}
```

However, the compiler complains that the `RefMut` I am returning outlives the lifetime of the closure where I create it.

Despite this, I've seen code which does something similar to what I'm trying to achieve -- for example [here](https://github.com/gyscos/cursive/blob/71a600cb9b02e66448ceb28877e8233fdf2f9f33/cursive/src/backends/crossterm.rs#L225):

```
impl Backend {
    pub fn init() -> ... {
        let stdout = RefCell::new(BufWriter::new(io::stdout()));
        ...
    }

    fn stdout_mut(&self) -> RefMut<BufWriter<Stdout>> {
        self.stdout.borrow_mut()
    }
```

What is the difference between these two use cases? What am I missing to be able to return the `RefMut` reference?

Answer (score 0):

`RefCell` checks shared mutable access dynamically, but it does *not* manage *ownership of the entire cell* dynamically (that's the job of things like `Rc`). A `Ref` or `RefMut` is only valid as long as the underlying `RefCell` exists, and that's why you can't return the `RefMut` from this closure: there's no guarantee in the structure of that code that the `RefCell` will continue existing. (There could be, if the type of `.state_mut()` specified a sufficiently long lifetime for the returned reference, but evidently it does not.)

In the second case, `stdout_mut` has elided lifetimes which link the lifetime parameter of the returned `RefMut` to the lifetime of `&self`, which provides the necessary guarantee. (If you change lint settings to `#[warn(elided_lifetimes_in_paths)]` then you'll get a warning whenever a lifetime parameter in a user-defined type is elided, which can help make this clearer.)

To solve your problem in the first case, you can:

- Change your structure to have `Rc<RefCell<_>>` instead of just `RefCell<_>`. Then you can return `Rc::clone(view.state_mut())` from the closure, and borrow it afterward.
- Borrow and make your changes within the closure.